# Iterate through record with index

Tags: delphi, record

I defined this packed record:

```
  TReplayData = packed record
    GameMode : Byte;
    VersionReplayCreation : Integer;
    BeatMapMD5Hash : String;
    PlayerName : String;
    NumberOf300s : Short;
    NumberOf100s : Short;
    NumberOf50s : Short;
    NumberOfGekis : Short;
    NumberOfKatus : Short;
    NumberOfMisses : Short;
    TotalScore : Integer;
    GreatestCombo : Short;
    Perfect : Byte;
    ModsUsed : Integer;
    LifeBarGraph : String;
    TimeStamp : Long;
    LengthInBytes : Integer;
    ReplayData : TByteArray;
    Unknown : Long;
  end;
```

And I want to fill it (**pseudocode**/not working):

```
  for i := 0 to SizeOf(TReplayData) - 1 do
  begin
    CopyMemory(ReplayData[i], AReplayBuffer + SizeOf(ReplayData[i]), SizeOf(ReplayData[i]));
  end;
```

This obviously doesn't work. *AReplayBuffer* is an *array of Char* which consists of all the needed data (sorted).

How could I fill the struct in a loop / is there even a way?

Comment: How do you get the char array in the first place? If you're serializing it at some place, it's probably a good idea to deserialize it in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First problem**

The FreePascal documentation: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types#ShortString states that the type String may refer to ShortString or AnsiString, depending from the compiler setting ({$H} switch).

The same page also says that "Internally, a variable of type AnsiString is treated as a pointer: the actual content of the string is stored on the heap".  So if this is the case, writing binary data over a pointer variable will result in an invalid pointer.

Solution: make sure you use `ShortString` (the size limit should not be a problem for MD5 and player name).

**Second problem**

You try to copy memory from the `ReplayData` member to the whole record which **contains** the ReplayData.  Even if you try to copy from two different instances of `TReplayData`, you will not have enough space.  Therefore `SizeOf(TReplayData)` will be greater than `SizeOf(ReplayData)`.

Solution: place `ReplayData: TByteArray` outside the record.  (N.B. TByteArray is defined to be 32767 bytes long, resulting in wasted space, see http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/tbytearray.html)

Comment: The question is tagged "Delphi", not FPC. There may be some degree of compatibilty, but that not always the case